# Flipping a fair coin 3 times. T/F

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

We flip a fair coin (independently) three times. Define the following two events:
A = "the number of tails is odd"
B = "the number of heads is even"
True or false: The events A and B are independent. (Recall that 0 is even.)

The answer is False, but I don't logically understand why, because if we know that if B occurs then we know that A also occurs. Does that means they are independent?

Answer (score 0):

If the number of tails is odd, then since we are flipping the coin 3 times, the number of heads must be even. 
Therefore, A is the same event as B and so they are very much not independent.

More generally, A and B are independent if and only if $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.

In this scenario, since $A\cap B = A$, they are independent if and only if $P(A)= P(A)P(A)$ which is only the case when $P(A) = 0$ or $1$. However, with the fair coin neither of these is possible and so the two events are dependent.